# Unable to get updates, how do i resolve the problem?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I am unable to fetch updates from the updates server. The screenshot above shows the message I got when trying to upgrade:

[image]

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Would you try to type 'sudo apt-get update' in a terminal and report what the output is ?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, a 404 Page Not Found error. I'd recommend starting off with some basic internet troubleshooting:

- If you're using Wi-Fi, disconnect then reconnect.

  - If that doesn't fix it, try rebooting the router.
- Can you load any pages at all? If not, get the bugs worked out of your internet. When you can reliably browse the web, try again.

If basic internet troubleshooting isn't cutting it, try temporarily changing your DNS (don't worry; this is not permanent, and is much easier than it sounds!)

1. Go to the Network Connections manager. (Click on your connection icon in the system tray and choose `Edit Connections`. The one accessable via the System Settings panel doesn't have what we need.)
2. Go to the appropriate tab (Wired/Wireless) and click `New`. Name it something like "Home Wi-Fi (OpenDNS)" or "McDonald's Wi-Fi (OpenDNS)" or "Auto Ethernet (OpenDNS)".
3. Enter the details of your connection, but don't click `Save...` just yet.
4. After you have all the appropriate details set up, go to the `IPv4 Settings` tab. (This procedure is identical for both Wired and Wireless.)
   Choose `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only`.
5. Okay, brace yourself, this is the *really*, ***really*** hard part, I mean it:
   Under `DNS Servers`, enter `208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220`. Now click `Save...`.
6. Disconnect from your internet, then (re)-connect to the connection you just created.
7. Now, type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
8. After you're done, go back to your "Normal" connection, or, just stick with OpenDNS. It is faster in most cases.

If all that still didn't fix it, perhaps you added a software source with a typo? That happens to the best of us... (aka me :P)